# Ignore command output when grep'ing

Tags: bash, docker, grep

I am trying to count occurrences of "POST" string inside docker logs

I am doing it like that:

`docker logs 2c02 | grep "POST" -c`

But I am getting not only the count of "POST" but also the full output of `docker logs`. Can I somehow ignore `docker logs` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker` prints to stderr. In bash you can do:

```
docker logs 2c02 |& grep "POST" -c
```